# Where does hdfs dfs -count get information?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

We need to count the number of files in lots of directories in a multi-tenant multi-node Cluster with lots of amounts of Data.
And so, I wonder from where the command "hdfs dfs -count /path/to/directory"
gets its information? Does it work like a hdfs dfs -ls? Or it gets its information directly from the Namenode in the HDFS?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It calls the `getContentSummary` method from FileSystem API:

```
ContentSummary summary = src.fs.getContentSummary(src.path);
out.println(summary.toString(showQuotas) + src);
```

Source code for [`org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.Count`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.3.0/org/apache/hadoop/fs/shell/Count.java?av=h)

Source Code for [`getContentSummary`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.3.0/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java#FileSystem.getContentSummary%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29)

Comment: Thanks! I see from the source code that it has a behaviour similar to the ls (it's a for loop going through the directories).

Comment: Yes, because `ls` prints the size of the file too.